# blogger to wp migration

Tags: xml, wordpress, blogger, add-on

Need to migrate 100 000 blogger posts to wp. I have tried using default blogger importer in wp panel and also tried to split the xml file and everything ends with failure. The xml file size 487mb.

How to migrate a blogger to wp?

Comment: What kind of error(s) you're getting? If the import file is 487MB - it's definitely too much. How large were the pieces you tried to split into?

Comment: I have made 50 splits and tried

Comment: If you're doing this on shared hosting - you probably hit resource limits. Try to run the import on your PC, just make sure to give enough memory and execution time to PHP.